# Focus on TextBox when UserControl change Visibility

Tags: wpf, user-controls, textbox, input, focus

I have a usercontrol loaded inside a canvas; this usercontrol on default have visibility collapsed. When a specific textbox of my window is focused the usercontrol become visible.

When usercontrol become visible I want set focus to another textbox inside usercontrol.

I try to do that:

```
private void UserControl_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
        if (this.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
        {                
            FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(this, TextBlockInput);
        }
}
```

It seems work but there is a problem: the textbox seems focused but the cursor into textbox don't blink and I can't type chars for input.

I would that after focus the textbox is ready for input. How can I do?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Well, I solve in this way:

```
private void UserControl_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate
        {
            Keyboard.Focus(TextBlockInput);
        }, DispatcherPriority.Render);
    }
}
```

I think that the problem was tha focus call into IsVisibleChanged event "scope"...right?

Comment: Was trying to solve this problem since this morning .... you saved my evening :-) Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
Keyboard.Focus(TextBlockInput);
```

see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768.aspx) for more details

Comment: I tried but worse...with Keyboard.Focus(myTextBox) or myTextBox.Focus() seems that textbox is not focused...don't see the cursor.

Comment: is it an standard TextBox? or some third part control?

Comment: I've posted my solution...thanks for help, seems that the problem was the focus call into IsVisibleChange event

Answer (score -1):

Another possible workaround is instead of `Visibility` property use `Opacity`. In this case calling `Focus()` actually sets focus.

Comment: It is a bad advice: `Visilibity.Collapsed` is very different than `Opacity=0`. Logical/keyboard focus, mouse events firing, theming, everything is different. `Opacity`is about aesthetics, `Visibility` is about the visual tree.

Comment: @Askolein As stated in my reply, it's a workaround, not a proper solution.